# Tensorflow not recognizing GPU (Anaconda)

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

Tensorflow is not recognizing my GPU. I have installed everything through `conda`. Using the following code to check:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('tensorflow: %s' % tf.__version__)
import keras
print('keras: %s' % keras.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

And got this result:

```
tensorflow: 2.3.0
keras: 2.4.3
Num GPUs Available:  0
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 10233889704466412734
]
```

I got theses packages installed at the moment:

[image]

I am using Python 3.8.5, Windows 10 and got a GTX 1650 Ti graphic card.

I have tried a lot of things i have found here on stackoverflow and other sites too, but nothing worked (for example, `remove conda tensorflow` and the same command for `tensorflow-gpu` and `keras`, followed by installing again using `pip install tensorflow`. Since it didn't worked, i installed again through `conda`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` versions are not supported. For [TF >= 2.5, you need `cudatoolkit=11.2` and `cudnn=8.1.0`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Comment: @Lescurel Oh i see... well, i just created a new environment with TF 2.6, cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.1.

Comment: Follow these steps `conda create -n tf_gpu python=3.8` and `conda activate tf_gpu` and `conda install cudatoolkit==11.2` and `pip install tensorflow`. Verify installation `import tensorflow as tf`  and `print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`. Thanks!